# Firebase dynamic link flagged as suspicious in Twitter and LinkedIn

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

During the past 12 hours we noticed that out Dynamic Link is marked as spam on Twitter and LinkedIn (only these social networks). The link worked properly for the past few months and the issue started 12 hours ago. 
Here is the link - https://ecs.page.link/...

Any idea what may cause/trigger this issue?
(please note that we have close relationships with Google on various on-going/future projects and the link is being used by our customers to share their content).

Thanks in advance,
Tal.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that they have reports that links under that domain have been reported before. It doesn't necessarily have to be your case. I will suggest you contact support and most probably they'll get it resolved. Companies have different mechanisms of triggering this type of alerts and they can probably add exceptions to your case.

an extract from Twitter faq: https://help.twitter.com/en/safety-and-security/phishing-spam-and-malware-links

> **My website is being flagged as unsafe**
>
> If you manage the website of a URL flagged as unsafe, contact Twitter Support. If the URL of the site you manage is being blocked, and you are completely sure that your site is not being used on Twitter for malware, phishing, spam or other violations of Twitter’s Terms of Service, you can contact our Support team by filing a case here. In the Problematic link field, please insert the extended URL of the link you are having issues with, rather than a shortened version.

Comment: Thank you. Issue started on Twitter and LinkedIn at the same time. It looks like Google Dynamic Link marked it as spam (and report it to partners).

Comment: It sometimes happen with Facebook as well. There is no way of avoiding this in the future. Even with Twitter support, it might get flagged again. Although I've seen that some links get flagged as first and later they're not flagged anymore. Anyways, good luck! I hope i could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new url prefix in firebase console. It should be yoursubdomain.page.link, not blabla.app.goo.gl